# Counting Distinct Items That Equal 0 Based On Another Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of 0s in a column based on conditions in another column. I have three columns in the spreadsheet: DATE, LOCATION, and SALES. Column 1 is the date column. Column 2 is the location column (there are 5 different locations). Column 3 is the sales volume for the day.

[image]

I want to count the number of instances where the different locations have 0 sales for the day.

[image]

I have tried a number of groupby combinations and cannot get an answer.

```
df_summary = df.groupby(['Location']).count()['Sales'] == 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try filter first:

```
(df[df['Volume']==0].groupby('Location').size()
     .reindex(df['Location'].unique())         # fill in the zero numbers
     .reset_index(name='No Sales Days')        # convert to dataframe
)
```

Or

```
df['Volume'].eq(0).groupby(df['Location']).sum()
```